# Meaning of $\langle X(t')X(t'') \rangle$?

Tags: notation, correlation-functions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

**Context**
My background is not in physics so I am not very familiar with the $\langle \rangle$ notation. I am trying to understand the following in a paper that I am reading (Berglund AJ., PhysRevE., 2010, page 3):

> "For the $k$th frame ending at time $t=k\Delta t$ the observed position $X_k$ is given by:
> $$
> X_k=\int_{(k-1)\Delta t}^{k\Delta t}s[t'-(k-1)\Delta t]X_{true}(t')dt'+\epsilon_k
> $$
> where $X_{true}(t')$ is the true position of the particle at time $t'$ and $\epsilon_k$ the value of the additive localization noise in frame $k$."

We also know that $\epsilon_k \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ and $s(t)$ is a non-negative function that integrates to unity (basically, the observed position $X_k$ is the average of the true position weighted by a camera-related function $s(t)$ over a timeframe interval of size $\Delta t$).

**Question**
The following is the piece that I don't understand:

> "From the equation above and the Brownian motion property
> $$
> \langle X_{true}(t')X_{true}(t'')\rangle=X_{true}(0)^2+2D\text{ min}(t',t'')
> $$"

What does $\langle X_{true}(t')X_{true}(t'')\rangle$ mean? Is it the average over all possible true position pairs? This would confuse me as the right side is mentioning min$(t', t'')$ so I assume that $t'$ and $t''$ are fixed?

**My Answer**

From the Brownian motion property we know that $X_{true}(t) = X_{true}(t-1)+\Delta_t$, with $\Delta_t$ independent and normally distributed centered in zero (i.e. $\langle \Delta_i \rangle=0$), and $\langle \Delta_{i}^2 \rangle=2D$. $\Delta_i$ is what is also known as the displacement!.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle X_{true}(t')X_{true}(t'')\rangle &= \langle [X_{true}(t'-1)+\Delta_{t'}][X_{true}(t''-1)+\Delta_{t''}]\rangle \\
&= \langle [X_{true}(t'-2)+\Delta_{t'-1}+\Delta_{t'}][X_{true}(t''-2)+\Delta_{t''-1}+\Delta_{t''}]\rangle \\
&=\ldots \\
&= \langle [X_{true}(0)+\sum_{i=1}^{t'} \Delta_{i}][X_{true}(0)+\sum_{j=1}^{t''} \Delta_{j}]\rangle \\
&= \langle X_{true}^2(0)+X_{true}(0) \sum_{j=1}^{t'} \Delta_{j}+X_{true}(0)\sum_{i=1}^{t''} \Delta_{i} +\sum_{i=1}^{t''} \Delta_{i}\sum_{j=1}^{t''} \Delta_{j} \rangle\\
&= \langle X_{true}^2(0)\rangle+\langle X_{true}(0) \sum_{j=1}^{t'} \Delta_{j}\rangle+\langle X_{true}(0)\sum_{i=1}^{t''} \Delta_{i} \rangle+\langle \sum_{i=1}^{t''} \Delta_{i}\sum_{j=1}^{t''} \Delta_{j} \rangle\\
&= X_{true}^2(0)+\langle \sum_{i=1}^{t''} \Delta_{i}\sum_{j=1}^{t''} \Delta_{j} \rangle\\
&= X_{true}^2(0)+\langle \sum_{i=1}^{min(t',t'')} \Delta_{i}^2+\sum_{j=min(t',t'')+1}^{max(t',t'')} \Delta_{j} \rangle\\
&= X_{true}^2(0)+\sum_{i=1}^{min(t',t'')} \langle \Delta_{i}^2 \rangle+\sum_{j=min(t',t'')+1}^{max(t',t'')} \langle \Delta_{j} \rangle\\
&= X_{true}^2(0)+min(t',t'') 2 D\\
\end{aligned} 
$$

Comment: $z=min(t',t'')$ means that either $z=t'$ when $t' \le t''$ OR $z=t''$ when $t'' \le t'$, there are given temporal instances when the statistical average of the product $\langle X(t')X(t'')\rangle$ of $X(t')$ and $X(t'')$ are calculated

Comment: Thank you @hyportnex , I think the word statistical average was very helpful. I just find the notation still confusing but I am getting it! I wrote down my own answer based on my new understanding of the notation. Thank you again.